# How do i check if something exist in a SQL db?

Tags: c#, sql

Right now using SQLite i write the below (I may move to either mysql or ms sql)

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT count(reset_key) user_data WHERE reset_key=@key;";
```

This works but is there a more optimized or cleaner way?

Comment: @acidzombie24: Did I not understand your question correctly? Doesn't the LIMIT clause help here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's about the cleanest, most optimized way there is. Make sure that there's an index on `reset_key` and it will be very, very fast.

Comment: Reading your comment on a post below i realized using an index column would be better. But, that doesnt matter if i must use a where? since i need to read the nonindex where column anyways? (if so then my code is fine).

Comment: The `where` column is the one that needs to be indexed, since that's what the RDBMS is filtering on.

Comment: > "That's right, how do you optimize something like that? "

If @reset_key is not a /unique/ key then the statement could be optimised by checking for the existence of a single row rather than counting all its occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  Select Case When Exists (Select * From user_Data
                           Where reset_key = @key)
              Then 1 Else 0 End
```

Comment: Do `select 1` instead of `select *`. No need to bring back the entirety of the column set when `exists` only cares about whether or not there's a row there. This would be slow if there's a `varchar(max)` field or something of that ilk. Also, this is really no faster than a `count` with an indexed column.

Comment: is that vb code? if your doing select * which returns all the columns then thats much worse.

Comment: @Eric,  Select * inside of an Exists does NOT bring back the entire row... It just checks to see if the row exists... exactly like Select 1 would do, but is the recommended syntax when using Exists().

Answer (score 0):

SQLite has the support of LIMIT clause. That might help.

EDIT: I don't know the SQLite syntax. But in SQL sense, it would look like

```
Select 1 From user_Data Where reset_key = @key LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I can't see how LIMIT would help if there is only every going to be, at most, one row.

Comment: @Dan: OP has asked for existence of records for a given criteria. If you do a SELECT with a LIMIT 1, if that returns 1 row - it means the record exists for given criteria & not otherwise. Did I understand the question correctly?

Answer (score 0):

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM user_data WHERE reset_key=@key"

if (commmand.ExecuteScalar() == null)
{
    //code for no matches here
}
```